# Typescript linter causes while mapping 'object possible undefined', when object already has been inspected by filter

Tags: typescript, dictionary, filter, undefined, tslint

Given this piece of code:

```
interface IProperty {
  property?: string
}

interface IEl {
  properties?: IProperty
}

const els = [
  { properties: { property: 'string' } }
]

const result = els
  .filter((e: IEl) => e.properties && e.properties.property)
  .map((e: IEl) => e.properties.property)
```

My tslint (5.11.0) throws an error: `"Object possibly undefined"` on `e.properties`. Which, fair enough, is true, taking the interfaces in regard. However, since I already filtered out all `e`'s that don't have a `properties.property` nested property, this error is too strict. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: this may help: [filtering-undefined-elements-out-of-an-array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135363/filtering-undefined-elements-out-of-an-array)

Comment: As a workaround you can try to use non-null assertion operator: `e.properties!.property`

Comment: @TmTron then you do another round through the array